# Marble toy with obstacle forms a normal distribution. Modify pattern to flatten the normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

I saw this toy where little marbles come from the middle, fall down while hitting a pattern of obstacles, and form a normal distribution.

How has the obstacle pattern to be modified, so I get a flatter/lower density normal distribution?

[image]

[image]

Comment: BTW, that's a [Galton board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galton_board)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a flatter distribution, you need to give the tiny balls more opportunity to spread out. Which is to say, the region of the toy with circular pegs where the balls bounce around must go on for more than the 12 rows that are currently there. We also still need to keep widening the peg pattern, and the whole toy, keeping the spacing between the pegs the same. Whether widening the pattern with a single peg per row is enough, or maybe even overkill in the long run I don't know.

Comment: I would argue the exact opposite. The resulting binomial distribution $B(n, 0.5)-n/2$ will approximate normal distribution $N(0, (\sqrt{n}/2)^2)$ and, keeping the width of $n$ constant (the width of the toy), the standard deviation $\sqrt{n}/2$ will shrink with growing $n$. It is really best to have $n$ as small as possible.

Comment: @StinkingBishop We would clearly need to increase the width of the toy as well, to avoid bounces off the edges to dominate the distribution too much. If we make the toy longer without making it wider, the distribution will go toward uniform. But increasing the width of the toy without changing the height will change nothing about the distribution. And reducing the number of rows of pegs will clearly make more balls land in the middle, giving us a narrower, denser distribution. Increasing the number of rows is what is needed to push more balls off to the sides, away from the middle.

Comment: Nothing bounces off the edge. This is a pure binomial distribution. I guess the critical question is - does the width of the toy increase with increase of $n$? If yes ($n$ bigger - toy wider - the centre of $\pm\sqrt{n}/2=\pm\sigma$ also gets wider) then you are right. If the width does not change but the pegs get more dense, then I am right.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I just read your comments more carefully. I agree more with you now. Yes, I meant to include widening of the toy, with more pegs per row, keeping the spacing constant. I have added that specification to my answer. Still, it's categorically not a pure binomial distribution (although I agree that it is approximated by the normal distribution). With the sideways velocity and random position the balls get as they go down a layer, and the possibility of bouncing several pegs to the side in a single row, pure binomial just isn't going to happen.

Comment: (You can even see it in the design of the toy. A pure binomial distribution would have no need of the outermost 5 or so columns on either side.)

Comment: True. I probably oversimplified the toy in my head. All I was trying to say - make the toy wider enough and the "centre" of the distribution will end up wider too. But then scale it down to the original width and you end up with a *narrower*, not *wider* distribution than the one you started with.

Comment: @StinkingBishop It is entirely common to think this toy is binomial. I have seen it many other places too. And yes, upon further thought, I agree that letting the number of pegs increase not linearly with the number of rows, but square-rootly with the number of rows is probably the best asymptotic approach to have the end result "feel" the same with respect to how the width of the final distribution fills the bottom part of the toy.